# How do I add multiple values to my dictionary key and then loop through them?

Tags: swift

```
var localConfig = [(String,String)]()

localConfig.append(("Hello","World"))

localConfig.append(("Bye", "John"))
```

**expected outcome:**

> [{"Hello": "World", "Bye":"John"},{etc},{etc}]

Comment: You do not have a dictionary but an array of tuples.

Comment: how would i change it to suit my outcome? adding values to my dictionary var dict = [:] dict["Hello"] = "World"?

Comment: please take a look at the most basic swift tutorial you can find, or even the docs https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html

Answer (score 0):

What you currently have is an array of tuples. The correct syntax for declaring a Dictionary is the following: `let stringDict = [String:String]()`

Then you can add a value to a specific key using the following syntax:
`stringDict["Hello"] = "World"`

You can loop through the key-value pairs of the dictionary using

```
for (key, value) in stringDict {
    print("Key: \(key), value: \(value)")
}
```

Or if you know all the keys, you don't need to loop through the dictionary, you can access them like this:

```
if let world = stringDict["Hello"] {
    print(world)
}
```

What you have in your question is an array of dictionaries. You can create one using the following code. Without knowing where and in what format your data is coming from, I can only show how to manually create the data structure with hardcoded values.

```
let output = [[String:String]]()
output.append(["Hello":"World","Bye":"John"],["a":"A","b":"B"])
```

Then you can iterate through this by

```
for dict in output {
    for (key,value) in dict {
        print("Key: \(key), value: \(value)")
    }
}
```

Comment: and then looping through them? to the expected outcome?

Comment: bare in mind i need to add more than one value to the same key

Comment: Why do you want to loop through them and what do you mean by "expected outcome"?

Comment: You cannot have duplicate keys in a dictionary by definition. So if you need to add multiple values to a  single key, you need to store them in a collection (i.e. an array) and set up the dictionary to accept an array of strings as values.

Comment: i want to loop through them so i can append them to a file in that order

Comment: Then why don't you write it to the file immediately? Dictionary is by definition unordered, so if ordering matters, you shouldn't use a Dictionary.

Comment: because i need to check if my values are true or false from me updating the values in my dictionary

Comment: I have updated my answer to show how you get the exact output mentioned in your question.

Comment: Thank you ill try it now with my values